# Herencia a un widgets con los métodos selecionados

Tags: python, pyqt5

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el comportamiento de un widget anulando sus funciones y agregando otras? ¿Se que puedo usar el mousePressEvent dentro de la clase win_layout, este código funciona pero vuelve a insertar otro QLabel encima del que ya tengo definido dentro de el archivo UI.

También e visto que definen el Qlabel con sus características fuera de el archivo Ui.

```
class QLabelClickable(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QLabelClickable, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setText("xdddd")
        print("xd")
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("xd")
```

Clase principal:

```
    class win_layout(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.setupUi(self)
            self.LePassword.setEchoMode (QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowSystemMenuHint)
            self.miminize.mousePressEvent=self.Clic_miminize
            self.exit.mousePressEvent=self.Clic_exit
            QLabelClickable(self.intUsuario)
```

Quiero asignarle a el `QLabel` las funciones de `mousePressEvent` con la herencia.

Uso el QtDesigner, el QLabel ya tiene todas las dimensiones, estilos, etc en el documento aparte (.ui).

Comment: Si lo he entendido bién, pretendes extender la funcionalidad de un QLabel implementado en QtDesigner haciendo que "herede" de tu clase `QLabelClickable`... No es posible, lo que si puedes es usar tu clase directamente  como widget en QtDesigner mediante un mecanismo conocido como promoción, no se si esto te serviría...

Comment: Si elimino el QLabel desde el Qt designer y creo otro identico en el codigo,Pero con las funciones extendidas ¿Seria una buena practica?

Comment: No hay problema, pero como comento puedes hacerlo desde QtDesigner, tiene un mecanismo pensado para poder usar widgets propios que hereden de lso widgets estándar de forma que podrás trabajar con el como si lo fuera (añadiendo estilos y demás).

Comment: Funciona gracias...